# How to update another div based on the index in ui-bootstrap carousel?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to show images in a carousel and is using ui-bootstrap carousel in my Angular-project. When a image is showing in the carousel I want to update another DIV with text related to the image.

```
<div ng-controller="carouselCtrl">
      <div style="height: 305px; width:205px; align-content: center">
          <carousel interval="myInterval">
              <slide ng-repeat="player in players" >
                  <img ng-src="data:image/*;base64,{{player.ProfileImage}}" style="margin:auto;">
              </slide>
           </carousel>
       </div>
 </div>
```

My player object contains information about a player that I want to show in another div under the carousel. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the plnkr referenced in the ui.bootstrap documentation you can specify an `active` attribute on your `slide` tag

```
<slide ng-repeat="player in players" active="player.active">
```

So you can have another ng-repeat under your carousel under the one you have above, and conditionally show based upon the active attribute. Or use a filter to get just the active one.

I've output the slides json in this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/PvSkL3M5MSiTF6UZiDYu?p=preview.)